# How can a Human Druid achieve expert proficiency with a weapon?

Tags: weapons, druid, proficiency, pathfinder-2e

How can a Human Druid achieve expert proficiency with a weapon?

It would be nice to have a feat for that, but I could not find any.
I would prefer a procedure that works for any weapon, but more limited solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Is this... any weapon? A specific weapon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At level 11, druids get the class feature Druid Weapon Expertise, giving them expert proficiency with unarmed attacks and all simple weapons. If they want expert proficiency in a martial weapon, taking the [Fighter Dedication and Diverse Weapon Expert archetype feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=7) gets them expert proficiency in all martial weapons.

Comment: I was hoping for something cheaper _and_ earlier

Comment: You might consider playing a fighter with Druid Dedication feats instead.